# Is it possible to execute a command on server even when I'm disconnected from remote?

Tags: linux, command-line, nohup

#### Scenario

I'm using `cp` to copy some very big folders, or using `tar` to compress some big folders. But I have very limited power on my laptop and can't find a power connection nearby.

#### Question

Is there any way to make the commands on my remote server continue to execute even if I'm disconnected due to a power off.

What I can think of is to put the commend in a `.sh` file and invoke that file with `crontab`, but is there any simple way?

Like `no_need_to_wait_for_me cp -r dir_old ../dir_new`?

Comment: Log in on the remote machine and start a `screen` or `tmux` session, then disconnect that session and reconnect later?

Comment: Side note: `tar` does not compress files. It only archives them. To compress you need to use a compression algorithm, such as `gzip`.

Answer (score 6):

Yes.  `nohup`.  Runs a command in the background, which continues running even if you logout.

```
nohup cp -r dir_old ../dir_new &
```

Answer (score 4):

Also you can use `tmux` or `screen` for running programs in the background.

[tmux](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki) is a terminal multiplexer. It lets you switch easily between several programs in one terminal, detach them (they keep running in the background) and reattach them to a different terminal.